# JTextArea appending and deleting problems

Tags: append, jtextarea

I have a jTextArea that displays the clicked item from a jTable. I have a running code already and I am able to display the strings into my jTextArea. However, I have an issue whenever I try to remove a string.

So far, below is my code for getting the string value from the clicked item in jTable:

```
c = jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(jTable2.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow), 1).toString(); // this will get the name of product from a table and store it into C variable
```

The string from above code will be displayed on my jTextArea, as shown below:

```
jTextArea1.append(c + "\n");
```

Now, whenever I click an item to my jTable this will be stored into c variable, and the new item will be appended on my jTextArea with next line.

My sample output in jTextArea of this will be:

**Apple

Mango**

Now, I want to delete a specific string from that jTextArea, which I am able to do so in my current code. I am using this line of code to do that:

```
 jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText().replaceAll(c, ""));
```

But then, whenever I clicked my jTable once again to append a new item, it will be appended next to the empty string, sample output is like this:

*// from here is the beginning of the jTextArea*

Mango
Apple

Now, I got empty strings before the new text is displayed.

In conclusion, I have understood that I never deleted an item from my jTextArea, but what it did was only to replace the string into an empty one. My problem is that I want to be able to append a string, then delete it whenever I need to do so without affecting the other appended strings, and without having an empty string.

Is there any other way to achieve this in replacement of my "replaceAll" line of code?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is analogous to editing a line of text to delete something in the middle. Naturally, you usually do not want a gap. One way to do this would be to copy the line over character by character but with a rule that if a space was preceded by a space it will not be copied (or, if a space comes up and is copied, then only characters will be copied that are not a space in that instance).

You could copy a series of records by reading each string, checking whether it had only spaces in it, and adding that string to the second screen only if it was other than white space.